# multiple conditions in inner query in django orm

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to perform a inner join query in django orm.

```
class A(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    text=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    c_id=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have the list of of names of class B.
I want to query such that i can get the `b_id` and `text` of model A for each name of model B whose `c_id=1` and `status=1`

can anyone please help how can do this??

edit:
i am looping over the list as,

```
for n in name_list:
    x=A.objects.filter(b__name=n, c_id=1, status=1).values('b__id', 'text')
    s=A(status=2,b_id=x.b_id,text=x.text,c_id=1)
    s.save()
```

This is how i want to use x.b_id and x.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you have a list with names, I think this could help you:

```
names_list = [ ... ]

A.objects.filter(b__name__in=names_list, c_id=1, status=1).values('b__id', 'text')
```

Where `names_list` is your initial list of B names.

EDIT:

From your edit I can see the problem you're facing. I think you will get an error in this line:

```
s = A(status=2, b_id=x.b_id, text=x.text, c_id=1)
```

because in `x = A.objects.filter(b__name=n, c_id=1, status=1).values('b__id', 'text')` you will get a `QuerySet` not an `A` object since you are using `.filter()` and not `.get()` method.

If you need to save a new entry with a updated status, for every `A` object that match your first query, you could try this:

```
for n in name_list:
    x_objs = A.objects.filter(b__name=n, c_id=1, status=1)
    for x in x_objs:
        s = A(status=2, b=x.b, text=x.text, c_id=1)
        s.save()
```

Comment: suppose i do x=(your answer). Will i be able to use x.b_id and x.run_id from this.because thats where i am facing the problem. ???

Comment: If you do x=(my answer), x probably will be a list, I think you will get many results, not only one, so if then you do x.b_id I don't think it will work, and I don't know what is x.run_id¿?. I think if you test my answer it will give the result you expect from the question, right?

Comment: i have edited the question what i am really trying to do. sory that x.run_id was some typing/copy error.

Comment: One question before edit my answer-> Why don't you just change x.status from 1 to 2?

Comment: i dont want to update the status, i want to insert entry for each name with updated status. there will be two entries in the db of the same name bu t with different status

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much for your help. IT worked. and taught me a lot.